# Log 4 net not logging to file

Tags: asp.net, logging, web-config, log4net

Probably a very simple setup, but I've tried to setup Log4Net. In my web.config I have:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="File" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Logs\\Log4Net.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd-HHmm" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="File">
      <level value="All" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

I have added the following to my configsections:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
```

The following in global.asax:

```
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

The following is on my default.aspx:

```
ILog alog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(_Default));
log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("File");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SetupSeo(); 
    }
    alog.Error("this test");
    logger.Error("Front page loaded for ip " + Request.UserHostAddress);
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess it is a Permission issue. The relevant directory do not have sufficent permissions so that ASP.NET can write to that.

To verify that, Enable log4net internal debugging by adding the below item to the `<appSettings>` section in the webconfig.

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
```

Now add the below to the webconfig as well

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add 
        name="textWriterTraceListener" 
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
        initializeData="C:\myLogFolder\log4net.txt" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Make sure that myLogFolder folder in C drive have permissions so that ASP.NET can write to that. This will write the internal debugging message to this file. Run the app and see what happens.

Comment: I add these settings to my web.config file, but even the internal debugging is not working, weird...

Comment: @KelvinHu Check the directory permissions

Comment: @Shyju Thanks, now I can write log after I changed a location.